# Генератор псевдослучайных чисел

Tags: c++

Пишу на С++. Задача в состоит в том, чтобы посчитать значения функции,используя генератор случайных чисел. E<=-0.02 a F<=0.02. Когда открываю файл, он оказывается пустым. Подскажите, в чем ошибка.

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <math.h>
> #include <cstdlib>
> ```

```
 using namespace std;

    int main () 
    {
    float t=0, b=0, c=0;
    bool E[1]={}, F[1]={};
    char  d = ';';   
    int i=0;

    FILE *file; 
    file = fopen("kola.csv", "w+");

    while  (i<=1001)
      {
        E[i]=rand()<=(-0.02);
        F[i]=rand()<=(0.02);
        t=t+0.01; 
        b=cos(t+E[i]);
        c=0.5*t*cos(t+F[i]);
        fprintf (file, "%f%c%f\n",b,d,c);

      i++; 
      }
    fclose(file);   
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @Мот, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

А вы на вывод программы хоть смотрели?

```
bool E[1]={}, F[1]={};
...
E[i]=rand()<=(-0.02);
```

Это что такое? Чему у вас i может быть равно? Больше же 1? Больше, значит и массив надо определять большим, либо вместо массивов использовать простые переменные (что будет разумнее)

---

Про вывод забыл написать, что программа выдает `segmentation fault`, что в данном случае как раз и означает выход за пределы массива

Answer (score 0):

А  еще у вас нет генератора случайных чисел реально, `rand` нужно инициализировать при помощи `srand (time(NULL));` иначе он все время выдает одну и ту же последовательность, еще надо добавить `#include <time.h>` . Строго говоря, ему можно скормить любой unsigned, но со временем проще всего